# Installation flash drive boots into a login screen

Tags: system-installation

The USB flash drive with the installation media boots to a login prompt!  I never see any GUI with any options! I suspect this problem is related to the ASUS motherboard (new Asus H670) and how it handles secure boot. Any clues from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

did you find a solution? I have the same problem with a new Gigabyte B660m motherboard and have not yet found a solution.

Do you have any Linux experience? If so, then you can log in with the username 'elementary' with no password and troubleshoot from there.

Are you using a dedicated graphics card or an onboard graphics card?